# Flutter Undraw Widget - PictureStream Error after update

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I encountered an error after i updated to Flutter 1.17 in the Undraw widget. It was working fine previously.

The code -

```
Container(
          height: height * 0.3,
          width: width,
          child: UnDraw(
              width: width,
              color: accentColor,
              illustration: UnDrawIllustration.medicine,
              placeholder: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              errorWidget:
                  Icon(Icons.error_outline, color: Colors.red, size: 50),
            ),
       ),
```

Dependency -   undraw: ^1.0.2

The Error I encountered -

```
abstract class PictureStreamCompleter extends Diagnosticable {

           ^
```

Compiler message:

```
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.13.1/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:92:3: Error: The superclass, 'Diagnosticable', has no unnamed constructor that takes no arguments.
  PictureStream();
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.13.1/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:192:16: Error: The superclass, 'Diagnosticable', has no unnamed constructor that takes no arguments.
abstract class PictureStreamCompleter extends Diagnosticable {
           ^
```

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 882
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

  > Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Here is the result of flutter doctor -

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
```

* [√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.778], locale en-US)

- [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
- [√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
- [√] VS Code (version 1.44.2)
- [√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!

Answer (score 0):

Try to access pubspec.yaml from undraw package and update the dependencies:

`flutter_svg: ^0.17.4`

`http: ^0.12.0+4`

If you still get some error after this, try forcing the same version of `flutter_svg` dependency on the `pubspec.yaml` from your application:

`flutter_svg: ^0.17.4`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade undraw to ^1.0.1 instead of ^1.0.2 and you can add flutter_svg: ^0.17.4, if you have upgraded your flutter to  Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.1, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G2022, locale en-ZA). Hope this help